# using ternary operator while printing in perl

Tags: string, perl, int, ternary-operator

Here is my code:

```
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
   if($i%15==0) print "Divisible by 15";
   else if($i%5==0) print "Divisible by 5";
   else print ($i%3==0)? "Divisible by 3":$i;
   print "\n";
}
```

Its a really simple code. I got it working in Java, though it gives an error in Perl.  The error is :

```
syntax error at line 2, near ") print"
Execution aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I'm new to Perl. How can I get it working?

Comment: To avoid fence post errors, use `for $i (1 .. 100)`.

Comment: try:  else { $s = ($i % 3 == 0) ? "xyz" : $i }

Comment: rolled back the additional question, since the user seems to have started a new question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651297/condition-in-ternary-operator-doesnt-cause-any-change

Answer (score 7):

Try this version:

```
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
   if ($i%15==0) { print "Divisible by 15" }
   elsif($i%5==0) { print "Divisible by 5" }
   else { print +($i%3==0)? "Divisible by 3":$i; }
   print "\n";
}
```

You need to add braces around the then-part of if statements and use `elsif` instead of `else if`.

Without the `+` in the `print` statement, perl parses the statement as:

```
print(...)  ?  "Divisible by 3"  :  $i;
```

ie. it will use the value returned by `print` as the first argument to the ternary operator. Another solution is to write:

```
    else { print( $i % 3 == 0 ? "..." : $i ) }
```

Comment: +1 excellent point on the parentheses being interpreted differently from the way that was expected.

Comment: Please see my edited question. Your suggestions worked correctly, but I was having another minor doubt.