# Condition in ternary operator doesn't cause any change

Tags: perl, ternary-operator, fizzbuzz

Here is my code sample:

```
for $i(1..100){
   if ($i%15==0){$s="Divisible by 15"}
   elsif($i%5==0){$s="Divisible by 5"}
   else {$i%3==0 ? $s="Divisible by 3" : $s=$i};
   print $s."\n"}
```

This displays partial correct results, if a number if divisible by 3, it displays the "number" and not "Divisible by 3".

Example of output:

```
1
2
3
4
Divisible by 5
6
7
8
9
Divisible by 5
```

PS: I have to write this code in the minimum no. of characters possible. (The reason why the code is so sluggish)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650715/using-ternary-operator-while-printing-in-perl

Comment: @squiguy: that started out as a different question; this question was added later, but I've rolled it back now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ternary `?:` has [higher precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) than assignment. Use parens to sort that out:

```
for my $i (1 .. 100) {
   my $s = "Divisible by ";
     $i%15==0 ? ($s .= 15)
   : $i%5==0  ? ($s .= 5)
   : $i%3==0  ? ($s .= 3)
   :            ($s  =$i);
   print "$s\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
Divisible by 3
4
Divisible by 5
Divisible by 3
7
8
Divisible by 3
Divisible by 5
```

Answer (score 3):

The fourth line is parsed as

```
(((($i % 3) == 0) ? ($s = 'Divisible by 3') : $s) = $i)
```

meaning that even when `$i` is divisible by 3, the assignment looks like

```
($s = 'Divisible by 3') = $i
```

Some fixes:

```
$i%3==0 ? ($s="Divisible by 3") : ($s=$i)
$s = ($i%3==0 ? "Divisible by 3" : $i)
```

---

Pro-tip: `B::Deparse` is very helpful for figuring this stuff out. I ran the command

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e '$i%3==0 ? $s="Divisible by 3" : $s=$i'
```

to see exactly what the problem was.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a version with less characters,

```
for $i(1..100){print(($i%3&&$i%5?$i:"Divisible by ".($i%5?3:$i%15?5:15))."\n");}
```

Parenthesis after the print function means call the print function, not group the expression. Caused by the fact that parenthesis are optional for that function.

Comment: I don't think `print (...)."\n"` does what you think it does.

Comment: @mob: Yes, you are right. But how will I achieve the new line?

Comment: @mob and xan I edited the answer to print the newline. I hope you are learning how perl apparently doesn't have the order of operations that you and I are guessing.